# How can I call super() so it's compatible in 2 and 3?

Tags: python, six-python

I'm trying to write 2/3 compatible code using `six`, but I don't see how I can call `super()` in a cross-compatible manner.  Is there some better way besides, for example:

```
class MyClass(MyBase):
    def __init__():
        if six.PY3:
            super().__init__()
        else:
            super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        ...
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) with arguments is backwards compatible, so you should just be able to use `super(MyClass, self)` without needing to check the version.