# how to call parent class methods in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I am writing a class in python.

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
    # build my objects 
    def foo(self,*args,**kwargs):
    # do something with them
```

Then I would like to extend this class:

```
class my_extended_class(my_class):
```

But I can not figure out what is the correct way of accessing parent methods.

Shall I:

1) create an instance of a father object? at constructor time

```
def __init__(self):
    self.my_father=my_class()
    # other child-specific statements
    return self
def foo(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.my_father.foo(*args,**kwargs)
    # other child-specific statements
    return self
```

2)  call father methods 'directly'?

```
def foo(self,*args,**kwargs):
    my_class.foo(*args,**kwargs)
    # other child-specific statements
    return self
```

3) other possible ways?

Comment: Use the super() function

Comment: would that work consistency across python versions 2.6 to 3.5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a parent class's method from child class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python)

Comment: yes, parameters to `super` are optional in python 3 but if you specify them for python2 compatibility it will work fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `super(ClassName, self)`

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
    # build my objects 
    def foo(self,*args,**kwargs):
    # do something with them

class my_extended_class(my_class):
    def foo(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(my_extended_class, self).foo(*args,**kwargs)
        # other child-specific statements
        return self
```

Compatibility is discussed in [How can I call super() so it's compatible in 2 and 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768391/how-can-i-call-super-so-its-compatible-in-2-and-3) but in a nutshell, Python 3 supports calling `super` with or without args while Python 2 requires them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [super()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) method. For example:

```
class my_extended_class(my_class):
   def foo(self,*args,**kwargs):
      #Do your magic here 
      return super(my_extended_class, self).foo(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

You might go to this link and find other answers as well.

[Call a parent class's method from child class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python)